# Lose leading zeroes when parsing String Array to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, android

I take `stringarrayI` from `SharedPreferences` and put this in a `String[]` split with delimiter `,`. Now I parse this into `ArrayList<Integer>`.

```
Log.d("stringArrayIget:", "" + stringArrayI);
String[] strArrayI = stringArrayI.split(",");
ArrayList<Integer> intArrayI = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < strArrayI.length; i++) {
    Log.d("strArrayI: ", strArrayI[i].toString());
    Log.d("strArrayILength: ", "" + strArrayI.length);
    intArrayI.add(Integer.valueOf(strArrayI[i]));
}
Log.d("intArrayI: ", Integer.valueOf(strArrayI[i]).toString());
```

I take `stringArrayI` from `SharedPreferences` and in Log I get `01234`.When I put that into `String[]` I get `01234`. But when I try to parse that into ArrayList I get only `1234`.

Answer (score 1):

If what you say is correct then your problem is that the string 01234 does not contain any commas. That is, the first log print you should see is 0,1,2,3,4 not 01234.

It is being "split" into an array of length 1. When you turn 01234 into an integer you get 1234.

Comment: oh i am so stupid.....this stringArrayI that i get from sharedpreference is just string.......

Comment: so how to parse this value 01234 from stringArrrayI to ArrayList<Integer>.Tnx.

Comment: can we assume the integers are >=0 and <=9?

Comment: yes.But if i need for some bigger values then 9 will be problem right? But nvm tell me for ntegers between  0 and 9.

Comment: tnx man nvm if its bad i need this for some small project for school.Tnx again.

Comment: why u delete your comment Astra Bear?